# How to deploy laravel application on my cloud server?

Tags: php, laravel, sftp

have server digitalocean cloud Ubuntu 16.04.2 x64 Apache 2.4 PHP 7.0.3 and SSL certificate Symantec, I was a Development application web site and am use Laravel 5 v 2.0 in localion host
what is a step for upload file in server cloud?
What is uplaod file in location to the server?
How to deploy laravel application on my cloud server?

Comment: you configured all the php apache mysql part ? only Laravel upload is the pending one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install Composer in your DO server. with the following command.

```
cd ~
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

We want to install it in a globally accessible location though. Also, we want to change the name to composer. We can do this in one step by typing:

```
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

Then install laravel in `/var/www` directory

```
sudo composer create-project laravel/laravel /var/www/laravel
```

Then give permissions to the directories. Then you can access the site by visiting `http://server_domain_or_IP`

Then to move the files you worked to the server. You need to create FTP. [Check this link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-vsftpd-for-a-user-s-directory-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Answer (score 0):

1. Apache Server Document Root

   ```
   DocumentRoot "/var/www/your-project-folder-name/public"
   ```
2. Restart Apache Server

   ```
   For Centos
   #systemctl restart httpd 
   For Ubuntu
   #service apache2 restart
   ```

   That's it.